# Vertically center text based on x-height

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to Vertically align a TextBlock based on [x-height (median line)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height). Not a hacky way either by setting a negative margin

Comment: TextAlignment="Center"

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian TextAlignment controls the *horizontal* alignment of text. The question is about *vertical* alignment.

Comment: I think in that case I like using a Label which has HorizontrolContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment